# Reinitialize the same MemoryStream, after setting the Position of that Stream to 0

Tags: c#

Imagine, is it a problem if I have method(`IDisposable` is implemented) where my private field is a MemoryStream it is initialized in the constructor.

Will my `IDisposable` clean up all resources ?

Declare it once private and initialize it once in the constructor:

```
private myMemoryStream;

MyConstructor(){
_myMemoryStream= new MemoryStream();
}
```

Reuse it in every method like this:

```
_myMemoryStream.Position=0;
_myMemoryStream = ...; //new stream
```

Clean up(IDisposable implemented in my class):

```
   public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_myMemoryStream != null)
        {
            _myMemoryStream.Close(/*todo: true oder false*/);
            _myMemoryStream.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Using that class in different contexts I will put a `using` around it.

Updated my question(based on @Oscar Vicente Perez suggestions), now I would use it that way ?!

Comment: updated my questio

Comment: If your reuse is like:

 `_myMemoryStream.Position=0;
 _myMemoryStream = ...; //new stream`

and `//new stream` is `_myMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();`

you are keeping the same problem I answer. If you need a better answer, put all your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Field != Object
>
> Field == Reference

A **field** just says **where an object is stored**, not store the object itself. But you are just changing where the reference points, forgetting the first `MemoryStream`. By doing that, you are leaving the cleans up of a `MemoryStream` to the `Garbage Collector`, and you can get some performance issues.

The fastest solution is to **Close/Dispose the current MemoryStream** before setting its reference to null. Also, if you just want to go to the start of the stream after a write to read it you can use `stream.Position = 0`

> Do not use a class field to hold temp variables that references different objects in every method.

Instead of:

```
private Stream field;
    
public void Method1()
{
    field = new Stream();
    ...
}

public void Method2()
{
    field = new Stream();
    ...
}
```

Use this approach:

```
public void Method1()
{
    using(Stream field = new Stream())
    {       
        ...
    }
}

public void Method2()
{
    using(Stream field = new Stream())
    {       
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but I want to use the `MemoryStream` across the entire class and if the use that class( implemented `IDisposable` ) i will put a `using` around it it, this is what I thought of....

Comment: If you are reading/writing always the same, you should use Position = 0. If your are reading differents things in differesnts methods i suggest you to use a local method field instead a class field in a Using statement.

Comment: @OscarVicentePerez - You say, "you are leaving the disposing of a MemoryStream to the Garbage Collector", but the GC never calls `.Dispose()`.

Comment: Good, but I am not using `field = new Stream();` in every method I just Iniatialized it once in the constructor and later in every method I use the field I set  the `Position` to `0` and than I put the new stream into and after the class is done my `Dispose` will clean up everything

Comment: @Enigmativity I never said that the GC will cal Dispose, i just say it will dispose the object. Actually he will call the ~Destructor, but he doesn't care.

Comment: @OscarVicentePerez - FYI, `MemoryStream` does not have a desctructor/finalizer.

Comment: @OscarVicentePerez - It would be better to say that the GC releases or cleans up the object to avoid confusion by using the word dispose.

Answer (score 0):

You should `Close()` / dispose of it explicitly when you are done with it and then set it to `null` if you really want to. Reinitializing the same field / variable won't cause any issue.

This begs the question why are you "reusing" your field in that manner? If you don't need the same *instance* of your `MemoryStream` across your class, it's probably a bit more readable to declare and use a new variable when you need to and `Close()` it when it's no longer needed.

Comment: Ok, but if I use `stream.Position = 0` I will be fine, to reuse the same `MemoryStream ` ?

Comment: I use the same private field across the same class, because I wanted to have tempory field, which will do the work, I wanted to have one place, some kind of worker.